# Google Maps Geolocation Services Not Working On Chrome

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps

I've been using Geolocation Services with a google API key. I got the code from this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/4ythpy02/).

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                      'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                      'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

It used to work perfectly until 2 days ago when it stopped working all of a sudden in Chrome and works perfectly in Firefox.

I know that since the release of Chrome 50 I must use Geolocation services from a secure location and that's not the issue, because even the fiddle is running through HTTPS.

I hope someone can point me in a good direction.